# Numpy cross covariance

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, covariance

Let `X` be a `(d_x,n)` matrix containing `n` observations of a `d_x`-dimensional variable `x`, and let `w` be a vector of weights (probabilities) of dimension `n`. The weighted covariance is given in `numpy` by

```
CX = numpy.cov(X, ddof=0, aweights=w)
```

Let now `Y` be a `(d_y,n)` matrix containing `n` observations of a `d_y`-dimensional vector. Is there a clever way to compute the weighted cross covariance, in pseudocode

```
CXY = sum(W[i] * numpy.outer((X[i, :] - X_mean),(Y[i, :] - Y_mean)))
```

?

Comment: Does `scipy.signal.correlate2D`[(link)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html) help at all?

Comment: I don't think so